# Excluding node_module from being written to the output file in webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs

I am trying to transpile es6 code to es5 using webpack and babel and in the js file I am importing jquery as below:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

So when I am building the code using webpack, the output file is getting the content of jquery along with the original transpiled code which I don't want to consume. I have added the exclude statement below to **webpack.config.js** but that doesn't seem to exclude the jquery part from getting appended.

```
exclude:path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
```

Here's what the **webpack.config.js** file looks like:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
   entry: { 
   copystyles: './src/copystyles.js',
   docErrorReporter: './src/docErrorReporter',
   },
   output: {
    path:  path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib'),
    filename: "[name].js",
   },
   mode:'none',
   module: {
      rules: [
         {
            test: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
            exclude:path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
            use: ['babel-loader']
         }
      ]
   }
};
```

Can anybody tell me if I am missing something here?
Thanks!

Comment: are you sure about `test:path.join(__dirname, 'src')` ? because i think it should be `test:/\.js/`

Comment: You can simply include a `<script>` tag in your `public/index.html` to load jQuery from a CDN - and then it will be globally accessible through `window.$` and not included in your bundle.

Comment: @AlanOmar Yes, this also works as intended

Comment: @VaishnavSivadas Did that solution solve your problem?

Comment: @IVOGELOV Thank you for this solution but it wouldn't be helpful in the scenario I am looking into.

Comment: @AlanOmar Nope, I didn't find a workaround for this yet. I tried using Browserify instead of webpack but getting the same result there as well.

Comment: The only way to exclude jQuery from your bundle is to not import it.